# cqengine: is the maven dependency on sqllite necessary?

Tags: java, cqengine

I am using cqengine with no particular setting and I have a 6MB maven dependency on sqllite.

I currently just use NavigableIndexes, so I am not writing anything on my disk, not explicitely that is, however I'm managing very big lists.

My question is: can I remove this dependency? Or cqengine, behind the scenes, actually makes use of it when RAM is not enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely remove that dependency if you are not using it.

I'm the author of CQEngine. The situation of which dependencies can be safely be removed should indeed be documented better. I'll try to do that in future.

Comment: Ok thanks! And good job with your project it is really awesome!